# Which features are scored first in Carcassonne?

Tags: carcassonne

I am playing with the The Gold Mines expansion in Carcassonne and I was wondering what the scoring order of features is. Which features do you score first?

I was playing and I placed a piece that completed both my mom's monastery and a road she shared with my brother. Gold was on the piece with the monastery and an adjacent piece and the road went through both those pieces. If the monastery was scored first my mom would get all the gold but if the road was scored first she would have to split it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Carcassonne Wiki [here](http://carcassonne.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gold_Mines) the rule is :-

> When players tie on a feature or when multiple features are scored together, gold is distributed to the involved players one bar at a time, beginning with the active player.

This view is also backed up by the [complete annotated rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules).  This document also says Rio Grande Games (RGG) and Hans Im Gluck versions both printed the rules slightly differently.

> The RGG version of the rules states “all players who score completed features with gold bars
>   take one gold bar for each feature they score and that has gold bars.” This seems different from the
>   HiG rules, where the rule is to only take one gold piece at a time.